# Android RelativeLayout height animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I am looking for height animation for `RelativeLayout`. Normally it should be starting from base value to the height of the layout. I was trying to write with [EasyAndroidAnimation](https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations) library. But could not succeed. Below code is attached. It is bouncing up from the base. I need something smooth.

```
new BounceAnimation(this.LayoutGraph)       
    .setBounceDistance(50)
    .setNumOfBounces(5)
    .setDuration(500)
    .animate();
```

Also I am looking for something easy like this as I have to use the approach for many layouts:

```
layout.startfrom(basevalue)
layout.to(height of the layout)
layout.animate()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**CODE Adding***

As Requested Please find the below code which I am trying.

I am calling the animation by calling the below code.

```
  expand(this.mFirstGraph);
```

**expand** method

```
   public void expand(final View v) {

            v.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            int i = (int)(0.075F * this.mWidthScreen);
            //this.mFirstGraph.getLayoutParams().height = i;
            int length=(int)(0.425F * this.mWidthScreen * (this.maxTemp - this.mWeatherModel.mWeekHighTemperatures[0]) / this.ratioTemp);
            final int targetHeight = i+ length;

            Log.e("BASIC5", "targetHeight: "+targetHeight);

            // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation a = new Animation()
            {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                            ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }

                public void animate() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };

            // 1dp/ms
            //a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            a.setDuration(2000);
            Log.e("BASIC5", "Duration value: "+ (int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(3));
            v.startAnimation(a);
        }




         public void collapse(final View v) {

            final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

            Animation a = new Animation()
            {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                        v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                        v.requestLayout();
                    }


                }



                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }



                public void animate() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };


            // 1dp/ms
             //a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            a.setDuration(200);
            //a.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            v.startAnimation(a);
        }
```

**Problems identified currently**

1. The animation is not smooth.
2. Height is not proper. Which I am currently working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this basic example could help you:

```
   public void expand(final View v) {

    v.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    //a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(3));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}




 public void collapse(final View v) {

    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }


        }



        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };


    // 1dp/ms
     a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    //a.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. got  some error while running. Will post you with results.

Comment: Hi Augusto, Thanks for your effort. After error handling I am able to work. Basically I found 2 problems. 1. **Its loading  too slow. Going very slowly** 2. **The height of the layout going Beyond of the relative Layout height.**

Comment: as you can see in the code i posted the animation duration is 1dp per millisecond. You can set duration as you want. For example: a.setDuration(200) and comment out the previous. Hope it's what you want ;)

Comment: Hi @augusto-picciani, I have edited the question and updated the code. Basically. I need to use this animation for more than 7 graph at a time and totally 50-60 times. So I was looking for some readymade library. Once again Thanks for your time

Comment: Hello Augusto, ping !